# How to create an interlaced h264 stream with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to create customized interlaced h264 streams, such as:

2:2, 3:2 pulldown, mix with mbaff, etc.

But all I know is to set AV_CODEC_FLAG_INTERLACED_DCT in AVCodecContext.flags, and set AVFrame.top_field_first, and they genreate MBAFF stream.

Do you have any suggestion for me ? Where can I get a related doc ?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Jinfeng, I think you'll have more luck asking this question here: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, it's a great QA website for me!

Comment: Stack Overflow is the proper place for FFmpeg libav* library usage. General ffmpeg cli questions don't get answered at [video.se] very often anymore ([last 7 days 100% unanswered](https://video.stackexchange.com/tags/ffmpeg/topusers)), and FFmpeg library questions are off-topic there.